# jquery modular ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone shed a light on this, so I have multiple `GET` ajax calls and its only a few lines of codes but I'm basically repeating `$.ajax({})` on every function.

Can I have 1 function of `$.ajax({})` instead and use this on the functions so I don't need to repeat `$.ajax({})` every time?

Something like this maybe but I'm sure its not right but its just a concept.

```
function ajaxCall(url, method) {
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: method,
   success: function(){ } // however this should come in the below function
 })
}

function firstCall() {
 var url = 'www.urlsample.com';
 var methodType = 'GET'
 ajaxCall(url, methodType).success() // get the data from this function?

}
```

Is this somehow possible to do? its to avoid repeating ajax call for every function.

Comment: You could do that, but all you're doing is wrapping `$.ajax`, so it's pretty redundant.

Comment: is there a better solution?

Comment: Not really. The pattern you're following offers no benefit over just calling `$.ajax` directly. If you want to set default options for all your AJAX request research `$.ajaxSetup()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.ajax()` method returns a Promise-Wrapper.

```
function ajaxCall(url, method) {
 // return promise
 return $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: method
 });
}

function firstCall() {
 var url = 'www.urlsample.com';
 var methodType = 'GET'
 ajaxCall(url, methodType).then(function( result ) { 
     // success handler
 }, function( error ) {
     // error handler
 });
}
```

Comment: how can you add error handler in the `firstCall` in case the call fails?

Comment: I just edited the answer to `.then()` which handles both, success and error handlers. IIRC jQuery's Promise-Wrapper also offers `.fail()` method for handling rejected promises.